# Why this kind of question is asked here even it is not helpful?

Tags: discussion, support

I found 1 question here is its link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136817/june-2012-community-moderator-election-results and here is its screenshot

[image]

But according to `faq`
[image]

This kind of should not be asked here.

So why this question is not get closed or deleted because it does not fit in `FAQ`.

Comment: I see your point.  It's not really a question.  But imagine it was:  "Who won the last election?"  That would be a good queston, right?

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is in the list of websites. The post you link is about the election on Stack Overflow. This is an unambiguously on-topic post, not sure what you're after here?

Comment: I am not after anyone.  My question is why this kind of un-useful question present here with so many upvotes.

Comment: You'll have to explain why you think that post is not useful, the election results are very important for Meta

Comment: Because `faq` states that `it's a place for improving our community and websites together`. How this question improves community and websites